# how to get cumulative amount of columns under certain criteria when skipping some of them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have a question with regards to getting the cumulative amount of some columns when skipping others (please see the picture).

Lets say on a certain row we have certain type of op units for which we have 3 columns for every month (Revenue, COS, G&A).  We have this for Jan, Feb, March and then 3 columns to total the amounts for quarter 1.  The next 3 columns are for April.

My question is how to make formulas that can add the cumulative amount for year to date in each category while skipping the Q1 amounts. I can do with offset but I can't skip Q1 column.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `SUMIFS` formulas that sum amounts in columns B:P for each category but exclude amounts where B1:P1 = "q1".  So for YTD Revenue the formula would be:

`=SUMIFS($B$3:$P$3,$B$2:$P$2,Q$2,$B$1:$P$1,"<>q1")`

Copy to the right into columns R:S and then down rows as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, BUT apologise I  dont think I was quite clear . The table continues until December, same manner, including q2 (sum of April -JUne) ,q3, (July-Aug),q4 (sep-dec) . After q4 there will be YTD column as required (revenue, sales, COS). I need when select the month to receive correct YTD figure. I can do with sum and offset , but how to skip q (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Where do you select the month?  Could you show what your YTD SUM/OFFSET formula is?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think that offset /sumif will work because of 3 different criteria.
Otherwise the month I will be selecting in row 1 after end of the table  (after Dec17 and Q4) there will be 3 foxed columns that will show YTD cumulative figure which should change when the month changes

Comment: Actually, Mark I took your idea for sumifs, I format properly Months and the last criteria will be "<=" appropriate month. This will exclude quarters and will sum all the months under these criteria. It worked for me. Thank you:)